# Excel PivotTable Different Sums per Row

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have categorized expenses in multiple currencies that I would like to display neatly in a pivot table. I have each transaction's value in a local currency and in USD. The goal is to show the sum of spending per category per month in USD, but also show spending in each currency in the same column.

Ideally, the PivotTable would show up as below. The category totals are the sum of spending in USD, whereas the currency totals are the sum of spending in that currency. So the category total deliberately does not match the currency total (i.e. $90 <> 20 + 64).

```
               May         Jun
Phone      $ 90.00    $ 253.10 
  EUR      € 20.00      € 7.00 
  USD      $ 64.00     $244.00
Food      $ 817.80    $ 196.14
  EUR     € 500.00     € 95.00
  USD      $ 43.00     $ 43.00 
  GBP      £ 80.00     £ 19.00
```

I understand that I could have two columns per month, one in USD and another in the local currency. But this would take up too much space in my spreadsheet.

The above output is based on the following data:

```
Date      Category  USDAmt   LocalAmt  Currency
5/1/2013  Food      14.00    14        USD
5/1/2013  Food      29.00    29        USD
5/1/2013  Food      650.00   500       EUR
5/1/2013  Food      78.00    50        GBP
5/3/2013  Phone     49.00    49        USD
5/3/2013  Food      46.80    30        GBP
5/15/2013 Phone     26.00    20        EUR
5/20/2013 Phone     15.00    15        USD
6/2/2013  Food      22.00    22        USD
6/3/2013  Food      21.00    21        USD
6/3/2013  Food      123.50   95        EUR
6/4/2013  Food      12.48    8         GBP
6/10/2013 Phone     230.00   230       USD
6/11/2013 Food      17.16    11        GBP
6/13/2013 Phone     9.10     7         EUR
6/13/2013 Phone     14.00    14        USD
```

I'm open to suggestions on other ways to nearly present the data and am happy to program whatever is needed in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Create the values in columns on your spread sheet and then hide the columns.  You can still use the values for your pivot table, and no one will be able to see them on your spread sheet.

Comment: You mean one column for USD and another for the local currency, I assume? The problem with hiding columns is that I want to combine data from the two columns. i.e. I'd want category totals from the USD column and the currency totals from the local currency column.